# Fixed column width with horizontal scrolling doesn't show when the column widths larger than container

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I am trying to have a table with fixed column widths and horizontal scrolling when the width of the columns is greater than the containing block.

The only time the fixed column widths work is when the sum of column widths < containing block (i.e. no scroll)

Otherwise, the fixed column widths seem to get ignored. Anyone know how to do this? here's my html and css.

```
    <div class="scroll-content-grid21">
    <div class="ExtraScrollableContainerDiv"> 
        <table class="regular" style="width:1440px"> 
            <tr>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Prev Qty</th>
                <th>Prev Amt</th>
        etc. more columns
            </tr>

            <% 
               for (int i = 0; i < this.Model.BusinessObject.Items.Count; i++)
               {
               %>
            <tr>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotReferenceNumber %></td> 
                    <td style="width:240px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotShortDescription%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotUnitRate%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotQuantity%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotUnitOfMeasureId%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].SnapshotAmount%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].PreviousToDateQuantity%></td>
                    <td style="width:80px"><%: this.Model.BusinessObject.Items[i].PreviousToDateAmount%></td>
        etc. more columns

            </tr>
        </table>


div.scroll-content-grid21
{
    overflow : auto; 
    width: 1072px; /* notice, smaller than the table width */
    height: 500px;
}

table.regular 
{
    table-layout:fixed;  
    margin-top: 0.1em; 
    margin-bottom: 0.1em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I can see is that you need to give width to your table header cells (th) as well. try this to see if it helps. Also have you given {overflow-x:auto} to td and th ?

Comment: For those who stumble on this question and answer while searching how to add automatic horizontal scrollbars to table columns, Valipour's point of adding overflow-x:auto; to the css or style="overflow-x:auto;" to the table is how to get automatic horizontal scrolling for large values in small column widths.  Thanks, Valipour!  Perhaps you should make that point larger instead of as an 'also'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample for anyone else who needs it:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div.outer
  {
            width : 500px; 
            overflow : auto;
  }
  table
  {
     table-layout:fixed; 
     width: 100%; /* same as containing div */
  }
  th, td
  {
            border: solid 1px #ccc;
  }

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="scrollable">
            <table>
                        <thead>
                                    <th style="width:50px">One</th>            
                                    <th style="width:300px">Two</th>
                                    <th style="width:200px">Three</th>
                                    <th style="width:200px">Four</th>
                                    <th style="width:200px">Five</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                                <td>001</td>
                                                <td>My really long description here</td>
                                                <td>10.0 units</td>
                                                <td>$100.00 dollars</td>
                                                <td>$1000.00 total</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                                <td>002</td>
                                                <td>This is number 2</td>
                                                <td>5 units</td>
                                                <td>$5.00 dollars</td>
                                                <td>$25.00 total</td>
                                    </tr>

                        </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```